# How do I convert a shapefile feature class from Angular Unit: Degree to linear feet?

Tags: arcmap

I have some ground receptors that are in decimal degrees and I need them to show linear feet instead. Does anyone know how to go about this?

```
GCS: GCS_WGS_1984
Datum: D_WGS_1984
```

Also, can someone please create a tag for LinearFeet?

Comment: So your data is in the wgs-84 coordinate system, you need to know the coordinate system you want to be in that has units in feet. I'm guessing a stateplane system. Find the coordinate system you want to use and then have the software re-project it.  Right now I would ask what would feet show, distance from where, what is the origin to start from... Your issue is Lat/Lngs from a round globe to a flat x,y Cartesian system.

Comment: That would make sense. I saw on a different project that it should be in NAD_1983_State_Plane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Feet. I tried this with the Project (Data Management) tool, but I need to be able to display the new values in the attribute table. I'll see if I can creatw new XY fields for this. Thanks!

Comment: ArcMap has an Add X,Y tool or add two fields (double so hey have a decimal) and then Field calculatore, calculate geometry. If your Esri based.

Comment: It already has XY data (POINT_X, POINT_Y) as this was done before I realized that my angular units were not right. I tried to run the ADD XY again, but there is a schema lock; also can't add new fields. I think I could calculate geometry if my system was a bit faster I'd know already. :-/ Thanks so much for your help.